# Backbone.js - Remove all sub views

Tags: backbone.js

I have a top level PageView that will re-render itself whenever the route changes.  I have many nested sub-views embedded into this PageView. If I was to re-render PageView, do I need to remove/unbind all the nested sub-views along with the PageView or do I only need to remove/unbind the PageView?  If I need to remove/unbind all the sub-views, what is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by unbind sub-views? Do you mean events?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, you need to properly remove and unbind them:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

The easy way to do this is to store an array of your sub-views in the parent view. Then in a `close` method on the parent view, loop through the array and call a `close` method on the child views:

```
ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.childViews = [];
  },

  render: {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      var childView = new ChildView();
      // do stuff with the child view
      this.childViews.push(childView);
    }
  },

  close: function(){
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
    // handle other unbinding needs, here
    _.each(this.childViews, function(childView){
      if (childView.close){
        childView.close();
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Be sure to call the `close` method on the parent view when you are ready for it to be removed / replaced. This will ensure all of the children are cleaned up properly (assuming all of them have their own `close` method).

Comment: Hey Derick, I have followed Your advice on this but I am experiencing really long delays when closing a view + it's child views. On some cases it can be as long as 5-10 seconds. It seems that the delay comes from this.remove(). Do You have any idea why?

Comment: that's rather long, and awful! I've never seen that happen, honestly... how large is the DOM structure that you're removing? My only guess would be a really slow browser, and / or a very large DOM node set.

Comment: Hey, nevermind - it seems that it's a problem with a jquery plugin instead that's somehow conflicting with the view's remove() function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877786/calling-jquery-remove-on-custom-ui-widget-causes-infinite-loop/9878287#9878287

Comment: You're missing a ')' at the end of the each statement

Comment: Derick, has your opinion changed on this at all in the past year? I'm considering throwing a global "PageChange" event that all views would then close to (including subviews), but I'm kind of leaning towards each page-level type view calling close on each of it's subviews which the app I'm developing is currently doing, just inconsistently.

Comment: i still use the technique described here. i've baked this in to my Marionette.js framework for Backbone apps, so I don't have to think about it anymore, though

Comment: As of 1.1.2, this.remove() also unbinds all events. so this.unbind() wont be needed. Subviews still need closing though..

Comment: I think it is better to close subviews before `this.remove();`. Is not it possible that `remove()` function also remove `this.childviews` ?

Comment: this was exactly the answer i was looking for, and the way i was thinking it must be done. MY GOD THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

A simple and modular class you might find useful.

```
ContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.children = [];
  },
  remove: function() {
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
    this.removeAllChildren();
  },
  removeAllChildren: function() {
    _.each(this.children, function(view) { view.remove(); });
    this.children = [];
  },
  appendAllChildren: function() {
    _.each(this.children, function(view) { this.$el.append(view.render().$el); }, this);
  }
});
```

usage:

```
MyView = ContainerView.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.removeAllChildren();
    this.$el.empty();

    // For each child view...
    // this.children.push(new SomeControl(...));

    this.appendAllChildren();
    return this;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of keeping an array of children view, could iterate through all the properties of your view and see which ones are an instance of Backbone.View; you will need to make sure to set a property for each child view in your parent view.

In the example below, the child views are set to properties of the parent view.  I'm not sure what the performance hit will be looping through all the properties, however, it may be easier than keeping track of a separate data structure for the child views.

**Example:**

```
var ContextView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      // views render themselves via their initialize methods
      this.titlebar = new TitlebarView({el: $("#titlebar")});       
      this.toolbar = new ToolbarView({el: $("#toolbar")});
      this.content = new ContentView({el: $("#content")});
    },
    removeChildViews: function() {      
        for(var prop in this){
            if (this[prop] instanceof Backbone.View) {
                console.log("This is a view: "+ prop + ' in ' + this[prop]);    
            }
        }
    }, 
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.el);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit like Zengineer wrote, i like to patch Backbone.View.remove globally like the following, so that any child views attached on this are removed

```
var originalRemove = Backbone.View.prototype.remove;

Backbone.View.prototype.remove = function ()
{

  for (var view in this){
    if (this[view] instanceof Backbone.View && this[view] != this) {
        this[view].remove();
    } 
  }


  originalRemove.apply(this, arguments);

}
```