# Killing views, global event bus. Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

I have a `PhotoCardView`:

```
var PhotoCardView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() { this.render(); },
    events: { 'click img': 'activateItem' },
    activateItem: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        bus.trigger('switchToFullScreen', {activatorId: this.model.get('id')});
    }
// ...
```

and parent `PhotosListView`:

```
var PhotosListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        bus.on('switchToFullScreen', function(args) {
            this.switchToFullScreen(args);
        }, this);
        this.render();
    },
    switchToFullScreen: function(args) {
        new ImageGalleryView({ 
            activatorId: args.activatorId,
            collection: this.collection 
        });
    },
 // ...
```

List view is handled at one of the application route handlers:

```
sampleRouteHandler: function(param1, param2, param3) {
    // ...
    photosList.fetch({
        success: function() {
            var photosListView = new PhotosListView({
                collection: photosList,
                page: p
            });
            $('#content').append(photosListView.el);
    // ...
```

Let's imagine I added code to 'kill' child views and parent view as it is described here [Backbone.js - Remove all sub views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522845/backbone-js-remove-all-sub-views)

But where should I initiate this? Also I don't know how to handle things with eventbus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add it in the close method for the view:

```
var PhotosListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        bus.on('switchToFullScreen', function(args) {
            this.switchToFullScreen(args);
        }, this);
        this.render();
    },
    switchToFullScreen: function(args) {
        new ImageGalleryView({ 
            activatorId: args.activatorId,
            collection: this.collection 
        }); /* not sure if you need to clean it up...if it has event listeners then you do */

    },
    close: function() {
        bus.off('switchToFullScreen', function(args) {
            this.switchToFullScreen(args);
        }, this);
        this.remove(); // removes this PhotoListView
    }
    ...
```

But you have to remember to call the close() method whenever you are getting rid of the view.

```
var viewInstance = new PhotosListView();

...

/*  getting rid of the view because 
you are going to another 'page' */

viewInstance.close();
```

See this example: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

Comment: *But you have to remember to call the close() method whenever you are getting rid of the view* that was the point - I didn't know how to implement check on transitions. though, that isn't hard. Thanks for the article reference. Ok I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to @redconservatory's answer.

1. I rewrote `PhotosListView` event subscribtion piece to that form:

   ```
   initialize: function() {
       _.bindAll(this);
       bus.on('switchToFullScreen', this.switchToFullScreen);
       this.render();
   },
   switchToFullScreen: function(args) {
   // ...
   ```

   to unsubscribe I use this at `dispose` method:

   ```
   bus.off('switchToFullScreen', this.switchToFullScreen);
   ```
2. Not sure if this is a best way to solve this, whether it's supported on any browser, but after equipping my application views with `dispose` method I added `StalenessValidator` to the router:

   ```
   var StalenessValidator = function() {
       var activeViews = {};

       function validate(view) {
           if(activeViews.hasOwnProperty(view.rootId)) {
               activeViews[view.rootId].dispose();
           }

           activeViews[view.rootId] = view;
           return view;
       }

       return {
           validate: validate
       }
   }();

   var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
       initialize: function() {
           this.viewValidator = StalenessValidator;
       // ...
   ```

   and then I call this:

   ```
   var photosListView = _this.viewValidator.validate(new PhotosListView({
       collection: photosList,
       page: p
   }));
   ```

   cool!